# ul li - how to center li when ul height is 100%

Tags: css

I need LI in UL middle and center

```
ul {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}
li {

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ezx2/1629/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options is to use `flexbox`:

```
// here extending your original css proposal

ul {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
li {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/37eekc8n/

Comment: Thank you! I'm try display flex but I forget "flex-direction". Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
ul {
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

That's all the CSS you need to vertically center your list-items. See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ezx2/1633/

Answer (score 0):

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ezx2/1635/

```css
div {
  background: green;
  position: absolute; 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
ul {  
 position: absolute;  
 width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align: center;
 top: 50%;
}
```

```html
   <div id="background">
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

One **div** to background and **top: 50%** property.

Hope that it help you.

Answer (score 0):

Supported in: **Chrome**,**Firefox**,**IE8+**,**Opera**,**Safari**

```css
div {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```